# Trying to add the following with crontab results in a "bad minute" error on line 2

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I'm at a loss for what I think may be a simple syntax error. What on line two is causing crontab to throw a "bad minute?" Thanks in advance for the help.

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep -fx "plexdrive mount -v 3 --chunk-check-threads=16 --chunk- 
load-threads=16 --chunk-load-ahead=16 --max-chunks=256 /home/username/files/Google/" > /dev/null
then
echo "Plexdrive is running."
else 
echo "Plexdrive is not running, starting Plexdrive"
fusermount -uz /home/username/files/Google/
screen -dmS plexdrive plexdrive mount -v 3 --chunk-check-threads=16 --chunk-load-threads=16 --chunk-load-ahead=16 --max-chunks=256 /home/username/files/Google/
fi
exit
```

The command: `pgrep -fx "plexdrive mount -v 3 --chunk-check-threads=16 --chunk-load-threads=16 --chunk-load-ahead=16 --max-chunks=256 /home/username/files/Google/"`
runs perfectly fine directly from the command line (returns the process number), so I'm pretty sure I'm just not understanding how to write a logic statement correctly.

Note: The server is remote and I'm merely a user. I have the ability to add to cron but not to services - hence this approach to solving the problem of ensuring that plexdrive (via fuse) always keeps this mount point alive.

Comment: How does crontab come into play here? Can you show the corresponding crontab line? Because I am pretty sure a "bad minute" error has nothing to do with your script (but rather with the minute column given in the crontab, which you didn't show).

Comment: It sounds more like an error in the crontab file. In each row there, the first 6[?] columns define how often the script is to run, and one of those is minutes - needs to be a number less than 60.

Comment: I'm adding the bash script provided by running "crontab -e." When I exit nano and try to save the content, I get the following:

crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.m1FUHS":2: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit?

The script provided is the only thing I have in cron at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, DevSolar. I'll dig a bit more. Support from the provider offering this server suggested this method and actually provided the script. I'll do some more homework. My own research suggests that a service is a better approach for what I want to accomplish. With these restrictions, etc. I'm probably better served picking on the server provider for support. Your direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Turned the comment into an answer for your accepting convenience. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* read up on [what a crontab should look like](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/). Not bash source, in any case. It's a configuration file to *start* (programs and) bash scripts, not to *contain* bash script.

A crontab line contains the following fields:

- minute,
- hour,
- day of month,
- month,
- day of week,

each of which specifying when to run the command, and

- the command to run.

I.e., if you want your script to run at five minutes after each full hour, and your script is named "my_check_script" (and in `PATH`), the crontab line should look something like this:

```
5  *  *  *  *  my_check_script
```

Check the linked documentation for more details.

Comment: Many thanks. This is definitely the route to go. Logic dicattes that it's much cleaner to pull that script content out into its own file. If I bump into any other issues, I'll hassle the server's provider.

Comment: @CharlieCampbell: The idea of a crontab is that of a *table* for *many* commands run on a regular basis, each on its own schedule. Your "watchdog" script is a workaround when you lack the resources / permissions / abilities to create a better solution. You have to make sure that 1) you don't repeatedly allocate resources or spawn processes that aren't reclaimed, and 2) your script / command does not generate output unless there is an error. Default behavior for cron is to put any output into a mail to the user, which can be intensely annoying when happening every minute. ;-)

Comment: @CharlieCampbell: (ctd.) Also, your provider might not *forward* that mail to you, instead flooding your account mailbox file until you run out of diskspace. Beware of automatted goodness. Good crontabs are a godsend, bad ones a nightmare. ;-)

Comment: Great advice! I've added the script to cron successfully but its output as is results in a dead.letter file which will only grow over time. I wouldn't have known to look for this otherwise. Thanks again!